# R Plumber API: Digital Ocean Connection Refused

Tags: r, digital-ocean, plumber

I've deployed a Plumber API to a Digital Ocean droplet on port 8000.  When I try to query using the `httr` package in R, I just get:

```
  Failed to connect to [[ip address]] port 8000: Connection refused
```

Where should I start with debugging?

Comment: Did you enable inbound connections to this port as described in their [documentation](https://www.digitalocean.com/blog/cloud-firewalls-secure-droplets-by-default)?

Comment: I just did now. Added both TCP and UDP inbound at 8000 and restarted the VM, same problem.

Comment: Probably the best way forward is to post a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code and a bit more debugging info, e.g. does this code work when you run it on your local machine; if so can you get a successful response on the Digital Ocean server when you query the API locally; also from another machine can you ping the open port on the Digital Ocean server?

Comment: It works now, I think I just needed to give the droplet time for all changes to take effect

Answer (score 0):

Had to add firewall in DO with tcp and udp port 8000